# Excluding Specific Feature classes from ModelBuilder iteration?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I am creating a model the will iterate through the feature classes in the dataset.

It will select attributes from each feature class, the only issue is, two of the feature classes will cause a break in the process due to being void of the attribute.

Is there a way to exclude the two said feature classes from the iteration?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112510/using-python-script-as-precondition-in-arcgis-modelbuilder which indicates how to employ if-then logic in ModelBuilder.

Comment: If you are using a FeatureClass iterator you can use the wildcard parameter to filter out the problematic FeatureClasses if they are name differently.

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

1. use the answer to [Using Python script as precondition in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112510) to employ if-then logic in ModelBuilder; or
2. do as commented by @Hornbydd:

> If you are using a FeatureClass iterator you can use the wildcard
>   parameter to filter out the problematic FeatureClasses if they are
>   name differently.